# Connect to the Sparx EA project on SQL Server with C# code

Tags: c#, api, enterprise-architect

I am relatively new to the Sparx EA. I am trying to evaluate the Sparx EA APIs. I am able to connect to the Sparx EA project stored in the .eap files using following C# code.

```
   r = new EA.Repository();
   bool isOpen = r.OpenFile("C:/Sparx-EA/Test Project.EAP");
   Element ele = r.GetElementByID(10);
```

This is giving me the element with Id 10.

Now I have transferred the project to the MS SQL Server, and created element on that project on MS SQL Server.

Now, I wanted to connect to the project that is stored on MS SQL Server with C# code. I have tried to find out the document and examples given by the Sparx, but they are most of showing the opening project from file.

Can some one help me to connect to the project stored on the SQL Server using C# code.

Comment: Try [Sparx Systems → Repository Class → OpenFile: ...You can also connect to a SQL database by passing in the connection string itself instead of a filename. A valid connection string can be obtained from the Open Project dialog by selecting a recently opened SQL repository...](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/automation_and_scripting/repository3.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either supply a connectionstring directly, or create a "shortcut" eap file using File|Save Shortcut

This will create a small txt file with .eap extension that contains the connectionstring.
You can then use this .eap file for your r.OpenFile operation.